# db2 rollforward command output show '-' in "Log FIles processed" column for non-Catalog partitions

Tags: db2, db2-luw, database-restore, roll-forward

I have rollforward the database after restore command. Below are the outputs of queries:

```
  db2 "rollforward db hdpf1 query status"

                                 Rollforward Status

 Input database alias                   = hdpf1
 Number of members have returned status = 3

 Member ID    Rollforward                 Next log             Log files processed        Last committed transaction
              status                      to be read
 -----------  --------------------------  -------------------  -------------------------  --------------------------
           0  DB  pending                 S0001422.LOG                     -              2019-10-22-17.26.46.000000 UTC
           1  DB  pending                 S0004726.LOG                     -              2019-10-22-17.40.25.000000 UTC
           2  DB  pending                 S0004583.LOG                     -              2019-10-22-17.52.59.000000 UTC
```

```
db2 "rollforward db hdpf1 to end of logs on all dbpartitionnums OVERFLOW LOG PATH ('/home/db2inst1/logs/db2inst1/HDPF1’)”
 
                                 Rollforward Status
 
Input database alias                   = hdpf1
Number of members have returned status = 3
 
Member ID    Rollforward                 Next log             Log files processed        Last committed transaction
              status                      to be read
-----------  --------------------------  -------------------  -------------------------  --------------------------
           0  DB  working                 S0001423.LOG         S0001422.LOG-S0001422.LOG  2019-10-27-07.32.56.000000 UTC
           1  DB  working                 S0004727.LOG                     -              2019-10-25-03.05.53.000000 UTC
           2  DB  working                 S0004584.LOG                     -              2019-10-25-03.04.32.000000 UTC
 
DB20000I  The ROLLFORWARD command completed successfully.
```

```
$ db2_all "db2 get db cfg for hdpf1 | grep -i 'First active log file'"
 
First active log file                                   = S0001421.LOG
db2 get db cfg for ... completed ok
 
First active log file                                   = S0004725.LOG
db2 get db cfg for ... completed ok
 
First active log file                                   = S0004582.LOG
db2 get db cfg for ... completed ok
```

It seems that the state before applying the log was :

1. For NODE0000, the log number was on: S0001421.LOG
2. For NODE0001, the log number was on: S0004725.LOG
3. For NODE0002, the log number was on: S0004582.LOG

Then the user provided the logs with below range :

1. For NODE0000 : S0001421.LOG - S0001423.LOG
2. For NODE0001 : S0004725.LOG - S0004726.LOG
3. For NODE0002 : S0004582.LOG - S0004583.LOG

Provided logs got applied to the database, I am not sure why the column "Log files processed " is blank for NODE 1 and 2.

I can see the log number changes in partition 1 and partition 2 (“Next logs to be read” column has updated)  but output didn’t show “Logs files processed” column for partition 1 and partition 2. What could be the possible reason?

`

> When i tried for another database, this value got reflected for non-catalog nodes also:
>   `

```
db2 "rollforward db hdpf2 query status"

                                 Rollforward Status

 Input database alias                   = hdpf2
 Number of members have returned status = 4

 Member ID    Rollforward                 Next log             Log files processed        Last committed transaction
              status                      to be read
 -----------  --------------------------  -------------------  -------------------------  --------------------------
           0  DB  pending                 S0000052.LOG                     -              2019-10-30-07.36.45.000000 UTC
           1  DB  pending                 S0000038.LOG                     -              2019-10-30-07.37.01.000000 UTC
           2  DB  pending                 S0000040.LOG                     -              2019-10-30-07.37.07.000000 UTC
           3  DB  pending                 S0000038.LOG                     -              2019-10-30-07.37.13.000000 UTC
```

```
db2 "rollforward db hdpf2 to end of logs on all dbpartitionnums OVERFLOW LOG PATH ('/home/db2inst1/log/HDPF')"

                                 Rollforward Status

 Input database alias                   = hdpf2
 Number of members have returned status = 4

 Member ID    Rollforward                 Next log             Log files processed        Last committed transaction
              status                      to be read
 -----------  --------------------------  -------------------  -------------------------  --------------------------
           0  DB  working                 S0000060.LOG         S0000052.LOG-S0000059.LOG  2019-10-31-10.32.32.000000 UTC
           1  DB  working                 S0000040.LOG         S0000038.LOG-S0000039.LOG  2019-10-30-07.37.01.000000 UTC
           2  DB  working                 S0000042.LOG         S0000040.LOG-S0000041.LOG  2019-10-30-07.37.07.000000 UTC
           3  DB  working                 S0000040.LOG         S0000038.LOG-S0000039.LOG  2019-10-30-07.37.13.000000 UTC

DB20000I  The ROLLFORWARD command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the Db2 level you are using? Are the two environments using different Db2 levels?

Since you mentioned db2 levels are same, please see following additional info:
The "Log files processed" reported can be less than what are really processed.  The true indication of what has been recovered is the "Last committed transaction" timestamp.

Comment: both are using same db2 version and fixpack i.e 10.5FP5

Comment: The "Log files processed" reported can be less than what are really processed.  The true indication of what has been recovered is the "Last committed transaction" timestamp. Which in your case was progressing.

Comment: I didn't get your statement 'The "Log files processed" reported can be less than what are really processed. The true indication of what has been recovered is the "Last committed transaction" timestamp'.  Could you please share any link or technote to go through the same in detail.